# parameter impurity given invalid value gini

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am reading [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=qSZKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=RandomForestRegressor%20setImpurity&source=bl&ots=aw206LAX-2&sig=G2-5Bk4Tzsv3wtSH7_I2YgwB9A0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4qPHi6vPeAhWRIDQIHd1tBFsQ6AEwCHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=RandomForestRegressor%20setImpurity&f=false) book. I am using Spark 2.4.0 on Scala 2.12 (standalone single machine cluster)

Based on this book's example I wrote this code

```
val model = new RandomForestRegressor()
 .setFeaturesCol("features")
 .setLabelCol("label")
 .setImpurity("gini")
 .setMaxBins(20)
 .setMaxDepth(20)
 .setNumTrees(50)
```

But I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
rfr_dc9303ee1fc9 parameter impurity given invalid value gini.
[error]     at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param.validate(params.scala:78)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamPair.<init>(params.scala:656)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param.$minus$greater(params.scala:87)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params.set(params.scala:737)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params.set$(params.scala:736)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.set(Pipeline.scala:42)
```

Full code at: https://github.com/abhsrivastava/allstate/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/abhi/RandomForestRegression.scala

Comment: gini is not an available option, variance is the only one according to the docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor. gini and entropy are options available with random forest classification

Comment: that resolved it thanks. I don't know why the book provided the wrong code sample.